# How to pass a string from one module to another in android studio?

Tags: android, android-intent, module

I have 2 modules in my project namely app and interface.
app has a dependency on interface. Now i want to pass a string from a class of the app module to a class in the interface module.
Lately i have been trying to pass the values using intents and bundles but i am retrieving a null value on the other end.

```
 Codes:
     app module:
    Class A:

        Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Interface.class);
        i.putExtra("x","test");
        startActivity(i);

    Class B:
      .... onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String value=b.getString ("x");
}
```

I am getting the value of x null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Class B you need to get String like below:

```
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("x");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the data:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("x");
```

Comment: great answer buddy you wrote extremely copied answer that already given